Unbound values not making sense
For some reason, I get that raise and = (for the id comparison) are unbound.
type id = string

let rec lookup (id: id) (storage: (id * 'a) list): 'a =
  match storage with
  | [] -> raise Not_found
  | (id', element)::storage' ->
    if id = id'
    then element
    else lookup id storage'

Also, in this case where value1 and value2 have the type int, I get that + is unbound.
let rec interpretExpression
  (expression: expression)
  (valueStorage: value_storage)
  (functionStorage: function_storage)
: int =
  match expression with
  | Id id -> lookup id valueStorage
  | Int value -> value
  | Add (expression1, expression2) ->
    let value1 = interpretExpression expression1 valueStorage functionStorage
    and value2 = interpretExpression expression2 valueStorage functionStorage
    in value1 + value2
  | FuncApp id ->
    let expression' = lookup id functionStorage
    in interpretExpression expression' valueStorage functionStorage

I found many other posts about unbound values for OCaml, but they were about

Not having evaluated bindings
Forgetting to use rec for recursive functions
Scoping

but raise, =, and + are all part of the core language.
Why I get unbound value for these operations?
Edit:


Can you share the exact error message you're seeing?

Does something like the following work? let foo () = raise Not_found

No, it doesn't. Maybe it's an issue with my configuration of ocamllsp.

Sidenote: your lookup is just List.assoc and you may wish to use something like a map instead of an association list.

Ah, that's amazing! Thanks for the tip on List.assoc. As for map, I tried to use it, but I couldn't get it to work. But I'll try again using the resource that you shared.

Thank you for that reference as well! I finally got it to work! Is there any way where I can avoid declaring a module just for id (an alias of string)? Currently, I have to define module Id = struct type t = id let compare x1 x2 = Stdlib.compare x1 x2 end, which seems overkill.

Looks like id is just string so Map.Make (String)?

Yes, that works. However, I'd hoped for something that would still refer to id, even though it's only an alias.

The issue was the ocamllsp.
I used the following guide to install the correct dependencies:
https://ocaml.org/docs/configuring-your-editor#visual-studio-code
The guide was essentially to install ocaml-lsp-server and 130 other dependencies by calling:
opam install ocaml-lsp-server ocamlformat
After that, I found that I had two different "Opam switches".
I opened the OCaml Platform extension tab in VSCode and changed the switch by clicking "Select a Sandbox" under COMMANDS, and choosing the local one.
You can confirm which switch is the right one for you by unfolding the switches under OPAM SWITCHES and seeing which dependencies they have installed.


Taking just your first example, I see no problems with the code. The toplevel accepts it with no error.
Looking at the image, it looks like the undefined symbol is "ocamllsp". This suggests there's something wrong with your LSP (langage processor for fancy GUI interface), not with OCaml itself.
I don't use LSP for this reason, i.e., on the way to being really nice it can cause configuration problems.
These things get very complicated, so you'll probably need to post full details of your setup to get help.

I found that I hadn't configured ocamllsp properly as you say.
I'm currently installing a lot of dependencies. I'll get back to you when it's done.
